# How to split a string by '.' in Haskell but if the period is in-between two numbers eg: (2.5) then don't split?

Tags: haskell

Could anyone help me implement a function that splits a string into an array of strings, split by a period (.)?

So: `"This is sentence one. This is sentence two."` becomes: `["This is sentence one", "This is sentence two"]`

**However, if the period is inbetween two numbers eg: (2.5) then don't split?**

Comment: We have multiple excellent solutions for parsing. Pick one. Google will help.

Comment: Based on your description, I'd expect the second element of your example list to have a leading space, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica, you're correct, bad example on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways you can do this. Here's a few.

With `Text.Regex`:

```
import Text.Regex.TDFA -- I think this will work with the other regex backends too

getAllTextMatches ("One. Two. a 3.5 b. cde." =~ "([0-9]\\.[0-9]|[^.])+" :: AllTextMatches [] String)
-- ["One"," Two"," a 3.5 b"," cde"]
```

With `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP` (in `base`, so no third-party libraries needed):

```
import Data.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

parseDigitsWithDecimalPoint = (\a b c -> [a,b,c]) <$> satisfy isDigit <*> char '.' <*> satisfy isDigit
parseNonDot = (:[]) <$> satisfy ('.' /=)
parseSentence = fmap concat . many $ parseDigitsWithDecimalPoint <++ parseNonDot
readP_to_S (sepBy parseSentence (char '.') <* eof) "One. Two. a 3.5 b. cde."
-- [(["One"," Two"," a 3.5 b"," cde",""],"")]
```

With `Text.Regex.Applicative`:

```
import Control.Applicative.Combinators
import Data.Char
import Text.Regex.Applicative

parseDigitsWithDecimalPoint = (\a b c -> [a,b,c]) <$> psym isDigit <*> sym '.' <*> psym isDigit
parseNonDot = (:[]) <$> psym ('.' /=)
parseSentence = fmap concat . many $ parseDigitsWithDecimalPoint <|> parseNonDot
match (sepBy parseSentence (sym '.')) "One. Two. a 3.5 b. cde."
-- Just ["One"," Two"," a 3.5 b"," cde",""]
```

With `Text.Megaparsec`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.Char
import Text.Megaparsec

parseDigitsWithDecimalPoint = (\a b c -> [a,b,c]) <$> satisfy isDigit <*> single '.' <*> satisfy isDigit
parseNonDot = (:[]) <$> anySingleBut '.'
parseSentence = fmap concat . many $ try parseDigitsWithDecimalPoint <|> parseNonDot
parseMaybe (sepBy parseSentence (single '.')) "One. Two. a 3.5 b. cde."
-- Just ["One"," Two"," a 3.5 b"," cde",""]
```

Completely by hand:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List.NonEmpty

foo = go id where
  go f "" = f "" :| []
  go f ('.':xs) = f "" <| go id xs
  go f (x1:'.':x2:xs) | isDigit x1 && isDigit x2 = go (f . (x1:) . ('.':) . (x2:)) xs
  go f (x:xs) = go (f . (x:)) xs
foo "One. Two. a 3.5 b. cde."
-- "One" :| [" Two"," a 3.5 b"," cde",""]
```

Comment: There has to be some way of making, or getting, a function that just takes a string, takes a regex, and splits the string. Every language except C and Haskell have this.

Comment: @AndrewKoster Isn't that what my `Text.Regex` way is?

Answer (score -1):

Use `Text.Regex.Posix` with this regular expression `\.(?![0-9])`.

Something like:

```
Prelude> :m +Text.Regex.Posix
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> getAllTextMatches $ "This is sentence one. This is sentence two." =~ "\.(?![0-9])" :: [String]
["This is sentence one", "This is sentence two"]
```

Comment: Is there any assumption for `:m + Text.Regex.Posix` to work? In my case I get an error, so I guess I should first install something.

Comment: Getting this error: `lexical error in string/character literal at character '.'`

Comment: That error is because the backslash needs to be doubled there. However, there's a bigger problem with this answer: `Text.Regex.Posix` doesn't support lookahead, so even once that's fixed, you'll just get `*** Exception: user error (Text.Regex.Posix.String died: (ReturnCode 13,"Invalid preceding regular expression"))`.

Comment: This isn't "splitting" a string, it's "matching" and extracting matches. Similar but different.